# Java Concatenate a txt list of words with one another

Tags: java

I am looking for the most efficient way to combine strings with one another from a list, I have around 2,000 words within a txt file that I read in and store within an arraylist, I then perform transformations on each of the words....I am now looking for a way to loop through the arraylist and perform all possible combinations of words (combining each word with every other word testing if it is correct then try another). So each concatenation will be two words, then try another two words....etc until all combinations are completed.

Comment: Just a heads up - that's 4,000,000 combinations you're looking at... Might be worth your time to see if you can improve your algorithm rather than look for the fastest way to create and test 4,000,000 words. What are you testing them for?

Comment: I completely agree with @Mshnik here.

Comment: its meant to be a brute force password cracker, basically have to use a dictionary to crack as many passwords as possible using multithreading we have 10 minutes to get as many as possible

Comment: @Mshnik 4000000 is not that much - for a computer at least.

Comment: The only thing is the dictionary I use will more than likely expand to a significantly higher amount in future, but as I say I have ten minutes so want to make good use of the time available.

Comment: @KieranWild looping recursively twice over a list of 2000 Strings takes ma 3 seconds or so (single core) - That's not much related to 10 min available

Answer (score 0):

I would use a nested foreach loop:

```
for(String one : list){
    for(String two : list){
        //...
    }
}
```

and concatenate `one` and `two` in both loops.